# Using 7-zip via system() in c++

Tags: c++, system, 7zip

I'm trying to use 7-Zip to zip up a file via the `system()` function in C++ on a windows XP machine.
I tried:

(formatted to be what system() would have received)

`"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "bleh.zip" "addedFile.txt"`

which spat the error

`'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I've tried several similar alternatives but have not yet found a solution.

I want to try to run it straight from its install directory so that as long as a user has 7-Zip installed it will be able to function. This is for an in house utility application.

EDIT:
as requested these are the actual lines of code:

```
std::string systemString = "\"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\" a -tzip \"" + outDir + projectName + ".zip" + "\" \"";
//...
std::string finalSystemString = systemString + *i + "\"";
system( finalSystemString.c_str() );
```

`*i` is an iterator to a particular file that is getting added.

Comment: Please post the actual line of code that calls system, that line of code is really important for answering this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks like something is stripping the quotes around the first argument.  You could play around with extra quotes to try and fix this, or you can get the MS-DOS compatible short path name for 7z.exe with the Win32 API [GetShortPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364989(VS.85).aspx)

The short path will not have spaces in it, it will be something like "C:\PROGRA~1\7-ZIP\7Z.EXE"

Comment: This might be a better solution than escaping it like I suggested, just because the double slashes are kind of awkward and the code might be clearer using the short path function.

Comment: I pasted that straight into my app and it worked! Thanks! Great trick to know!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried escaping the spaces, i.e. "C:\Program\ Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"? That might work, although I don't know the specifics of system().

Comment: Same result, however that caused MSVS to throw this: 
warning C4129: ' ' : unrecognized character escape sequence :(

Comment: @0xC0DEFACE: Try "C:\\Program\\ Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe"

Comment: As expected that caused the \ to escape the \ resulting in "C:Program\ Files\7-Zip\7z.exe".damn

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use the [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) function in the Windows API. It can deal with spaces in "C:\Program Files" according to its documentation.