# How can I compress or pack files in c++?

Tags: c++, compression, packing

I am trying to compress or pack multiple files in different formats into one.
I am using c++ and was wondering if there is sth which is easy to use and preferably in one class or library. performance does not matter that much

Comment: [zlib](https://www.zlib.net) is easy to use and works well for that purpose.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you. Would you please help me in its usage?

Comment: I couldn't hope to do better than the excellent [zlib manual](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html). I suggest reading that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is out of scope here... it's just the language you're using.
Standard Library is getting richer and better but it doesn't contain anything related to compression (and probably never will).

You can find a 3rd-party library for this, like zlib... :-)
https://www.zlib.net/

You can also find for "zlib c++ wrapper" on Google if want want something "more C++"

Comment: I'm finding it hard to use zlib. Could you please provide some help? I couldn't figure out anything from the documentation.

Comment: google for zlib examples... zlib website has a very detailed explanation... https://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html

Answer (score 0):

you could use 7z via system. In my experience it's quite simpe/quick/reliable.

[Using 7-zip via system() in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227038/using-7-zip-via-system-in-c)